# Connection timeout error using MongoDB in docker compose

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask

I'm getting this error when trying to add data to MongoDB via a Flask app. MongoDB and Flask app are services in my docker-compose.

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.0', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /this (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10cd54190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, g
from flask import request
from pymongo import MongoClient


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/this', methods=['POST'])
def this():
    db = g.conn.warehouse
    clx = db.this
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        print(data)
        clx.insert_one(data)


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    MONGODB_HOST = 'mongodb'
    g.conn = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, 27017)


@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    g.conn.close()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:5000
    links:
      - mongodb
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  mongodb:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

requirements.txt

```
flask
pymongo
redis
```

In a notebook, I'm trying to make this POST request

```
import requests
requests.post('http://127.0.0.0:8000/this', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, json={'a': 1})
```

Comment: The Compose `links:` option is obsolete, and activates an archaic Docker networking mode.  Does deleting that block help?  (You don't have to replace it with anything, Compose automatically creates a more modern Docker networking setup and between these containers the service names `web`, `redis`, and `mongodb` should be usable as host names.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, deleting `links` does not help.

Comment: 1. Make sure you set the FLASK_APP environment variable. 2. You are connecting to `127.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Maybe there's something I'm missing but connecting to `127.0.0.1` returns `404` error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follow:

- docker-composer.yml

  ```
  version: "3.8"
   services:
     web:
       build: .
       ports:
         - 8000:5000
       links:
         - mongodb
       environment:
         - MONGODB_HOST = mongodb
     redis:
       image: "redis:alpine"
     mongodb:
       image: "mongo:latest"
       hostname: mongodb
       ports:
         - 27017:27017
       volumes:
         - mongo_data:/data/db

   volumes:
     mongo_data:
  ```
- app.py

  ```
   @app.before_request        
   def before_request():    
       MONGODB_HOST = os.environ('MONGODB_HOST')
       g.conn = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, 27017)
  ```

Comment: This did not work. Same issue.